# Display file version previews via Box Content API

Tags: box-api, boxapiv2

I'm curious if anyone has insights on whether the Box API allows for displaying previews of previous versions. I've experimented with embedded links, but it didn't work.

```
curl  -X GET \
  'https://api.box.com/2.0/files/11111/versions/2222?fields=expiring_embed_link' \
  --header 'Accept: */*' \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer token'
```

My goal is to develop a web integration app that can present different versions side by side, a feature currently missing in Box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found how to do this with content preview ui.
https://github.com/box/box-content-preview#parameters--options

```
      var preview1 = new Box.Preview();
      preview1.show('54321', 'token', {
        container: '.preview-container1',
        fileOptions: {fileVersionId: '12345'},
      });
```